# EOCD Signature not found

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

I am working on a Firebase Android project. When I try to run the app from Android Studio, it is showing an error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.io.IOException: EOCD signature not found in the last 22 bytes of the file.
```

Actually, I can not figure out what is this problem and why it is showing.
Is there anyone who can help me out?

Comment: Okay.I have found the solution.After enabling multidex support,app is working fine.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Answer (score 41):

removing the output apk file will probably help.
days and hours wasted on you, Android studio

Comment: removing from the emulator?

Comment: @Saurabh no, the output file, in project path

Comment: That worked for me, thanks.. ahh so awful android studio..

Comment: thanks man , you saved me!

Comment: After 4 hours got your solution and works for me.

Answer (score 22):

I faced this error with another error simultaneously: 
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug' - Failed to read zip file.

Both the issues were solved together by

1) Killing the process of OpenJDK Platform Binary from Task manager

2) Deleting the apk file.

3) Restarting the Android Studio

4) Clean Project

This solution might not be relating to the question asked but it worked for me to solve both the errors.

Comment: I tried to clean the project but it failed as some of the files in build/intermediataries/transform folder were used by OpenJDK Platform Binary. I tried to manually delete the folder through explorer but failed. After killing OpenJDK Platform Binary, everything became normal. Probably a bug in it.

Comment: I had the error "EOCD starts at ... but file..."  Steps 1 & 2 worked for me while Android Studio was still open.

Comment: yes only doing 1 & 2nd step solved my problem . .Thanks

Comment: Agreed...steps 1 & 2 solved the problem

Answer (score 15):

Deleting app-release.apk and output.json from release folder then 
1. Clean
2. Rebuild

These steps worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

Just matter of deleting app-release.apk. Then rebuild the project. This worked for me.

[image: app-release.apk location]

Comment: android studio makes no sense.

Comment: yes @Sergio, until we get the perfect answer on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Just follow these 2 steps:

1. Clean Project
2. Rebuild Project

Answer (score 2):

These are the steps:

1. Remove the whole build folder (Go to Project view to find it easily)
   [image]
2. Clean the project
3. Run the project again and should be installed

Answer (score 1):

This also happens when you are building splits apks while renaming your output files to the same name

Answer (score 1):

May be its late , but i seem to have an explainable fix for the EOCD issue.
It can be fixed by enabling multidex in your project.

**Step 1:**
In app/build.gradle
In android block

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

**Step 2:**
In dependencies block add the multidex gradle dependency

```
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

**Step 3:**
Go to app/AndroidManifest.xml file
if you have declared an application through name attribute , open that class file that extends Application and replace it with MultiDexApplicaation.

```
public class ApplicationController extends MultiDexApplication
```

Now build your application, EOCD error will be fixed.
Atleast in my case it does.

Comment: I did all the steps and now getting following error 'Could not find method multiDexEnabled() for arguments [true] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.'

Comment: @IrshadBabar may I know the gradle distribution version and gradle plugin version you are using. In my case it is distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip and gradle plugin is 3.0+

Answer (score 0):

Delete build file from your project directory and try again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i bought i new brand cable for debugging